# OSX File permissions and inheritance when copying files

Tags: mac, permission

OSX: High Sierra

I have 2 drives mounted. The drive I am copying files from has permissions of 700 and when I copy them to the second mount (NFS) I want them to have 755. How can I get inheritance to happen during this copy action (so the files land at my target with 755)?

Currently the files land on my target NFS server with 700 and no one else on the share can access them.

More information: I am using a creative program that writes directly to the first drive with 700 permissions and I am unable to change that (I may look into the idea of changing this but its storage managed by some people offsite).

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question!